# Approve ListItem using Javascript in Office365

Tags: client-object-model, office-365, content-approval

I'm trying to approve selected items from a list by pressing a custom button in the Ribbon. I can get the selected items. I can get the fields of the selected items.I can even update those fields.

The problem is approving an Item. I can't find a way to do it. I've tried something similar to what it's done with CSOM in C# but my only option is the javascript object model. How do I get the Approved status? How do I change it? (note that I have content approval enabled)

```
    function onRequestSucceeded() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);

        for (var idx in selectedItems) {                       
            var selectedItem = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItems[idx].id));

            var listItem = selectedItem;
            context.load(selectedItem);
            context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)); }

function onQuerySucceeded() {
            alert("onQuerySucceeded!");
            console.log(selectedItem.get_item("ModerationStatus"));
            if (selectedItem.ModerationInformation != null) {
                selectedItem.ModerationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Approved;
                selectedItem.ModerationInformation.Comment = "This is comment generated";
                selectedItem.update();
            }                   

            context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                alert("urray!");
            }, function () {
                alert("fail");
            });
        };

        function onQueryFailed() {
            alert("fail");
        };
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Microsoft API. I'm using the web services to deal with the Sharepoint list. With Web Services you'd have to set the column "_ModerationStatus" (with underscore) to 0 to have your item approved.... If you don't mind using a third party library you can look at http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.list.html#.moderate -- but it hasn't been tested with Sharepoint 2013/Office 365

Comment: Thanks for your help AymKdn. But I prefer to stay away from 3rd parties as much as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to approve items selected in List View via JSOM

```
function approveItems(success,error) {
   var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
   var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
   var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);

   for (var idx in selectedItems) {                       
       var selectedItem = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItems[idx].id));

        selectedItem.set_item('_ModerationStatus',0);
        selectedItem.set_item('_ModerationComments','');
        selectedItem.update();
   }  

   context.executeQueryAsync(
       function(){
           success();
       }, 
       error
   );   

}
```

> Note: the approval is performed as a batch operation for selected items

Usage

```
approveItems(
 function(){
     console.log('Approved');
 },
 function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
 }
);
```

Comment: that did it! thanks. the documentation on msdn is so poor that I couldn't find anything about this. the best that I have is:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201.aspx.
Can you advise me a better link about JSOM?

Comment: MSDN doesn't cover all the cases when working with JSOM I'm afraid. I would say SP JavaScript library code base in some cases is the only way to figure out..