# JSOM - Page Approval with JS

Tags: javascript, jsom

I write down a JavaScript to reset news likes. It is working properly. But I need to checkOut the file while trying to edit news properties.

```
  ResetNewsLike = function () {
    var pagesListItem = this.opagesListItem.getEnumerator();
    var list = this.list;
    while (pagesListItem.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = pagesListItem.get_current().get_fieldValues();
        var result = { ID: currentItem.ID };
        var currentWeb = clientContext.get_web(); var ListItem = list.getItemById(result.ID);

        var file = ListItem.get_file();
        file.checkOut();
        ListItem.set_item("LikedBy", "");
        ListItem.set_item("LikesCount", 0);
        file.checkIn();
        ListItem.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(result, GetNewsComment), Function.createDelegate(this, Log.Error));
    }
}
```

**What did I try to solve this problem :**

I tried to use approve method of file but It didn't work.

```
file.approve();
```

Then I tried to set _ModerationStatus but It didn't work too.

```
ListItem.set_item('_ModerationStatus', 0);
ListItem.update();
```

The question is what is the proper way to approve checkedOut file with JavaScript?

Comment: Hi Onur, I think already somebody answer this question. could you please try this Stackexchange link .https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/102055/approve-listitem-using-javascript-in-office365

Comment: Hi Vinit, I already tried that way, I tried it after ListItem.Update() and It says "The file is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes". If I try before ListItem.Update() It says "You cannot change moderation status and set other item properties at that same time"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was order of the methods. We need to update item first then we can approve it.

```
 file.checkOut();
 ListItem.set_item("LikedBy", "");
 ListItem.set_item("LikesCount", 0);
 ListItem.update();
 file.checkIn();
```